# round up a momentjs moment to nearest minute in timeunit

Tags: typescript, momentjs

I want to change time like following by momentjs

when timeunit is 30 minute

2019-12-05 10:36:33 -> 2019-12-05 11:00:00

2019-12-05 10:13:33 -> 2019-12-05 10:30:00

when timeunit is 60 minute

2019-12-05 10:01:33 -> 2019-12-05 11:00:00

2019-12-05 10:50:33 -> 2019-12-05 11:00:00

How can i simple do that??

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
import * as moment from 'moment';

function roundTime(input: string, uint: number) {
    let time_unit = uint;
    let minute = moment(input).minutes();
    let step = (((minute / time_unit) + 1) * time_unit) - (minute % time_unit);
    return moment(input).minute(0).second(0).add(step, 'minute').format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
}

let out1 = roundTime('2019-12-05 10:36:33', 30) ;
let out2 = roundTime('2019-12-05 10:13:33', 30) ;
let out3 = roundTime('2019-12-05 10:01:33', 60) ;
let out4 = roundTime('2019-12-05 10:50:33', 60) ;
console.log(out1);
console.log(out2);
console.log(out3);
console.log(out4);
```